# How to find $a$ and $b$ if $f(x)=ax+b$ (read body to understand)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

$f$ linear function defined on R:$f(x)=ax+b$
So we have: $f(b)=2+f(a)$  and  $f(-1)=1$
Then find $a$ and $b$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I found $f(x)=2x+3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are told that f(x)= ax+ b.
You are also told that $f(b)= ab+ b= 2+ f(a)= a^2+ b+ 2$
and that $f(-1)= -a+ b= 1$.

So $a^2- ab+ 2= 0$ and $b= 1+ a$.

$a^2- a(1+ a)+ 2= a^2- a^2- a+ 2= 2- a= 0$
$a= 2$.

$b= 1+ a= 1+ 2= 3$.

y= ax+ b= 2x+ 3.

Check: f(b)= f(3)= 2(3)+ 3= 9 while 2+ f(a)= 2+ 2(2)+ 3= 9
and f(-1)= 2(-1)+ 3= 3- 2= 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

$f(-1) =1$ and $f(-1) = a\cdot (-1) + b$ so $-a + b = 1$

And we have $f(b) = 2+ f(a)$ but $f(b) = a \cdot b + b$ and $f(a) = a\cdot a + b$

So $2 + (a\cdot a) + b = ab + b$.

.....

So that's that:

$-a + b =1$ and

$2 + a^2 + b = ab + b$.

So solve for $a$ and $b$.